# The equivalent definition of a non-degenerate symmetric 2-tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space. We say that a symmetric 2-tensor $q$ on $V$ is non-degenerate if the linear map $\hat{q}:V\to V^*$ defined by $\hat{q}(v)(w)=q(v,w)$ is an isomorphism. Now I would like to prove that the following two statements are equivalent:

(a) $q$ is non-degenerate.

(b) For each nonzero $u\in V$, $\exists w\in V$ s.t. $q(u,w)\neq 0$.

---

I have shown (a) implies (b), and it's quite straightforward. It remains to show (b) leads to (a), and I must prove that $\hat{q}$ is an isomorphism. This can be done by showing that $\hat{q}$ is injective and surjective. Actually, all we need to do is justify the injectivity of $\hat{q}$ since $\hat{q}$ is a linear map between vector spaces of equal dimension. But somehow I can't work it out. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a question about quadratic / bilinear forms, not differential geometry, so I changed the tags

Comment: It's enough to show that if $u$ is nonzero, then $\hat q(u)$ is nonzero. By assumption, there exists a $w$ such that $\hat q(u)(w) = q(u,w) \not=0$, which seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $\hat q : V \to V^*$ as $\hat q (u) = \left(v \mapsto q(u,v)\right)$. This is a linear map between spaces of the same finite-dimension. We have:
$$
\ker \hat q = \{ u \in V \mid \hat q (u) = 0 \} = \{ u \in V \mid \forall v \in V, q(u,v) = 0\}.
$$
Hence, it follows that $\ker \hat q = \{0\} \iff (b)$.
Therefore:

\begin{align}
 (a) = q \text{ is non degenerate } & \iff \hat q \text{ is an isomorphim }\\
& \iff \hat q \text{ is injective} \\
&\iff \ker \hat q = \{0\} \\
&\iff (b).
\end{align}